# Error importing mnist dataset from tensorflow and ssl certificate error anaconda

Tags: tensorflow, ssl-certificate, anaconda, mnist

I have no idea what the problem is. I am trying to import the mnist data set from the tensorflow examples and I am finding it very difficult to proceed.

So far: I saw the SSL certifications error, so I tried the following:
1. pip remove certified and pip install certified
2. read a lot to fix the SSL error, all in vain.

I think the issue is with the importing the mnist library as It says:

*`from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`*

*`mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("tmp/data/", one_hot=True)`*

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-3-7da058911bcf>:1: read_data_sets (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use alternatives such as official/mnist/dataset.py from tensorflow/models.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/prashanth/Downloads/[/media/sf_H_DRIVE/UBUNTU/Anaconda]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py:260: maybe_download (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please write your own downloading logic.


WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/prashanth/Downloads/[/media/sf_H_DRIVE/UBUNTU/Anaconda]/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py:219: retry.<locals>.wrap.<locals>.wrapped_fn (from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.base) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use urllib or similar directly.
```

Config of the python I am using:
I am using anaconda and I have pip installed tensorflow. Sorry if the question isn't framed properly. This is my first question on stack, any links to solution is also enough. Please Help me! :) Thank you

## Errors

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Comment: Please do not post images when you can post a text

Comment: Thank for tip :)

Answer (score 2):

I just had same issue like you, and resolved by run /Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command....just double click that :-)

FYI: 
It's a  Python 3.6 on MacOSX has no certificates at all (see the release notes), so it cannot verify the SSL certificate from GitHub's servers when trying to download housing.tgz. 
The solution is to:
1. read /Applications/Python 3.6/ReadMe.rtf
2. the ReadMe will have you run /Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command which installs the certificates.

Thanks to ageron@github: 
https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues/46